# drop table which has primary key and foreign key

Tags: mysql

I want to drop all the table in mysql, what should I do first? drop primary key? foreign key? and how to drop them
Delete from customer, invoice, item, invoice item;
Drop table invoice_item;Drop table invoice;Drop table customer;Drop table item;

Comment: You cannot delete a table that has foreign key references _from_ it to existing rows in another table. First drop the table that has references _to_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command-line you can do this..

This works even for tables with foreign key relationships which is what you need.

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] \
  --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | \
  grep -e '^DROP \| FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' | \
  mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

You can also do something like this which will allow you to drop the table

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
drop table if exists tableName;
drop table if exists tableName;
drop table if exists tableName;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```